# How to reinstall nameresolution on messed server

Tags: networking, dns

I've messed up my server which runs on Ubuntu 18.10 (played with docker and pihole).

I don't have any name resolution on the server.

How to fix that ?

My current investigations :

- internet connection is available, I can download files using ip adresses
- I've been able to download the iso file of the server (ubuntu-18.10-live-server-amd64.iso) using the ip address of ubuntu's download server
- `ping askubuntu.com` returns `ping: askubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`
- I don't have `/etc/resolv.conf`
- my netplan file is set to use dhcp (actually file wasn't modified) :

  ```
  network:
      ethernets:
          enp2s0:
              addresses: []
              dhcp4: true
      version: 2
  ```
- ifconfig does not display dns server set up in the dhcp server (but not sure if it's supposed to)

I'm a beginner in nix server administration, I wish I won't have to reinstall the server.

My first goal is to restore network usage on the server, using the dns server defined by the DHCP server.

My next goal will be to use pihole from a docker container as primary dns server and the DHCP's DNS server as a fallback (or a static DNS server). But that's another question

Comment: You can get yourself going by creating your own `/etc/resolv.conf`. It has two lines, `search somedomain.com` and then `nameserver <nameserver ip>` you don't need the search domain for internet. This is used to resolve computers on the local lan. The nameserver ip should be set to the dns resolver on your lan. That should get you going at least, this way if you want to install packages, or change from netplan to NetworkManager for example you can

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 has reached end-of-life. Please upgrade. https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-18-10-reaches-end-of-life/

Comment: Please try: `ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` Is there any improvement?

Comment: @stratus: adding manually my dns server allows me to resolve name. But what about next ? It seems to me a workaround, isn't it ?

Comment: @chili555: there's no folder `/run/systemd/resolve`. Maybe a missing package ? Regarding your warning, I will upgrade my server, but I have to fix it before

Comment: "adding manually my dns server allows me to resolve name." Considering what you may have deleted or modified, this may be the best course of action; a workaround that "works."